# Hover boxes on wordpress theme with conflicting code

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I am currently using the following script (effect 3):
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/

I am trying to make these boxes show on my blog content listings, which currently uses the content feature.  I have included the call for the CSS and JS of the demo file for this effect;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

I have added this to the index.php file rather than the header, as I only need it on this page. Currently, I have this so only the featured image/embed shows for the blog listing. I removed any wordpress title and excerpt tags as I wanted to focus on getting this to work before adding in the content. So, currently, it's just a copy of the code used in the demo combined with the code for the blog listing itself. Shown here is the image post.

```
<ul class="grid cs-style-3">
  <li>
    <figure>        
    <?php
    }

    if ($format === 'image') { ?>

      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="post-image" >                                  
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>

        <figcaption>
          <h3>Settings</h3>
          <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
          <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

This is where I am getting a little bit lost and maybe this is down to too many scripts on the same page, as the blog listing itself uses webkit coding to display.  But I have copied all the code exactly as it was in the demo, minus the image section which is my blog code instead. But no matter what I try it just shows without the effect and under the image.  I am completely lost as to what to do here and out of ideas.

I have tried searching, but nothing has helped. So I am thinking this is more down to the coding I already have for the theme not playing nicely with this code. I have managed to add additional sections in the same way, but not get extra code to work with the themes functions itself.

You can see the page I am referring to and where it has gone wrong here, under any of the images:

http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/blog/

Happy to provide anything else extra.

Full code: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6152

Comment: I'm having problems with the effect on firefox. It works fine on chrome though.(I'm talking about the original website demo)

Comment: ok so first of all there is a closed bracket `}` with no matching open bracket at the beginning of the php code. That may be a problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up on Firefox.

Do you know which line the closed bracket is? I am unable to see any without a opening one..

Comment: I mean line 5 of the snippet you posted

Comment: Also you're not closing the brackets for any of the `if` statements

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has some problems, try replacing it with this. I just removed the brachet I was talking about in the comment, and added the `endif;`s at the end of the block. I still have no idea if the $format variable is correctly populated elsewhere in your code, so there may be other issues.

```
<figure>        
    <?php if ($format === 'image') : ?>
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="post-image" >                                  
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
            <figcaption>
                <h3>Settings</h3>
                <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>

            </figcaption>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>    
</figure>
```

Comment: I think I should have posted more of the code as this broke the code up, but this is my fault for not showing the whole thing.

I've added the full page here;
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6152